# INVALID_SESSION_ID using REST API through Postman

Tags: rest-api, postman

I am using Postman for some time now and it always worked. It seems that something has changed as I can directly authorize through OAuth and immediately after it all subsequent requests fail:

> "Session expired or invalid"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To add to Semmel's action (which helped me as well) alternative is to make API call in postman to a different address (and thus not having redirect that you can observe in Postman console).

Use :

> https://<custom_domain>.**my.salesforce.com**/services/...

Instead of UI address:

> https://<custom_domain>.**lightning.force.com**/services/...

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. I will look into it. Thanks for the addition!

Comment: This solution worked for my case.

Comment: Since you supplied the "more correct" answer I will accept yours instead. To add to it (and make it 100% correct), always use the instance URL you got with the token instead of just using your custom domain - that way it will also work for sandboxes.

Answer (score 9):

Okay - I already found the answer. It seems there's now a (new?) option in Postman that needs to be turned on:

[image]

Credits for this go to Ayisha Begum and the answer here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000099xAIAQ

Comment: Thanks. This answer helped me too..

Comment: This has to be turned on because the request is most likely sent to the "wrong" URL. You have to send it to the instance URL you get as part of the process (together with the token) - if you don't do that your request needs to be redirected to the correct URL hence that's why you need this option.

Answer (score 0):

The Follow Authorization Header no longer seems to be a Postman setting;

For me the solution was to add the Authorization Bearer  under the Headers tab in Postman - not under the Params tab.

Answer (score 0):

Correcting Super Nova
Follow Authorization header still exists in Postman  under 'Settings'.
Turning it on helped me